# .htaccess redirect ignoring criteria

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am currently updating a website and having to add some 301 redirects for some old pages that we no longer use. My code is;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Redirect 301 /old-folder/old-file.html http://www.newsite.com/new-folder/
```

Unfortunately the redirect seems to be ignoring the html file part so when I visit the old link I will get redirected to

```
http://www.newsite.com/new-folder/old-file.html
```

Anything after the first child is ignored and when I try to redirect a more complex url with this code;

```
Redirect 301 /old-parent-folder/old-child-folder/old-page.html http://www.newsite.com/new-folder/new-page.html
```

I then get redirected to a broken url such as;

```
http://www.newsite.comold-child-folder/old-page.html
```

That isn't a typo either, after the .com the slash is completely ignored.

I hope you can see the problem here, htaccess seems to just look at the first part of the old structure and ignore the rest causing all sorts of issues and strange links.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `RewriteEngine On` Or `RewriteBase /` because the `Redirect` directive is not a Rewrite.

However, I would use Rewrite to do what our are wanting to do. It's more powerful and you can control the URI easier with regex if needed.

instead of this.

```
Redirect 301 /old-folder/old-file.html http://www.newsite.com/new-folder/
```

Use this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^old-folder/old-file.html http://www.newsite.com/new-folder/ [R=301,L]
```

Note that there is no prepending `/` in the rewrite. This is on purpose.